# jQuery AutoComplete missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I was building something using jQuery's AutoComplete plugin last week, but today I found that it's not working.

After some debugging, it seems that the external scripts I've been loading no longer exist:

http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.bgiframe.min.js

http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.dimensions.js

http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js

Even the demo on the plugin page no longer works:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Was the plugin deprecated over the weekend and I didn't know it? Or is there some way to let them know that the files aren't showing up?

Comment: I'm not sure you're meant to link directly to these scripts?  You'll be a bit stuffed if they change (as they have).  I think google have static links that you can use for these files, but otherwise, I think they should be downloaded and included with your site.

Comment: @Paddy - +1, though this should really be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to the static delivery on the google CDN:

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/

I'm not sure they do the plugins, but you can get the main library this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some quick links to get your missing scripts:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Like @Paddy said in the comments above, I would HIGHLY recommend pulling these down into your project and creating local references to each instead of relying on the FQDN of the scripts on another host to remain unchanged forever.

UPDATE:
Note that I myself have noticed some downloads going missing recently on jquery.com, so you may have trouble finding the downloads.  If so, I would recommend checking if google's cache has a hard link to them - I've been able to find a couple this way.